# Can't lock one view controller in Portrait , xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to make only one view controller locked in portrait while allowing all other views to be any orientation. This is what i have tried to put in my homeViewController ( the one i want to keep in portrait).

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    }
    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I am trying to do this in xamarin in c#. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: Your code is right for a `UIViewController` that is `PresentViewController`ing another `UIViewController`.... but are you using `UINavigationController`? And/Or is your `homeViewController` the first VC that is shown on app launch(?) and must be in portrait and all VCs after that are orientation unlocked?

Comment: Yes i am using UINavigationController. The homeViewController is the first one loaded. I just want that view locked in portrait and the rest in any orientation.

Answer (score 3):

Add This in AppDelegate.cs

```
    public bool RestrictRotation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And Add this in same AppDelegate.cs but after FinishedLaunching() method

```
    [Export("application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:")]
    public UIInterfaceOrientationMask  GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, IntPtr 
        forWindow)
    {
        if (this.RestrictRotation)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        else
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    }
```

Add following to every viewcontroller which you wish to make Portrait

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        this.RestrictRotation(true);
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    }

    void RestrictRotation(bool restriction)
    {
        AppDelegate app = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
        app.RestrictRotation = restriction;
    }
```

Comment: CORRECTIONS: 1) to these Portrait VCs, add `ViewWillDisappear` that does `app.RestrictRotation = false;`. Otherwise, your app may be stuck in Portrait. 2) Use `ViewWillAppear` instead of `ViewDidLoad`; otherwise a return (pop) to an existing view won't restrict.

Answer (score 1):

I derive my controllers from one base. I need this for other purposes but also use to lock portrait orientation

```
public class BaseView : UIViewController
{

    static List<Type> SupportingLandscapeScreenTypes = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(TemperaturesHistoryView), 
        typeof(LoadSwitchConsumptionView), 
        typeof(HomeConsumptionGraphView)

    };

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        foreach (var screenType in SupportingLandscapeScreenTypes)
        {
            if (GetType() == screenType)
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight;
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    }

}

public class MyEnergateAppNavigationController:UINavigationController
{
    public MyEnergateAppNavigationController(UIViewController rootController)
        :base (rootController)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    //[Obsolete ("Deprecated in iOS6. Replace it with both GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations and PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation")]
    //public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    //{
    //    return TopViewController.ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation);
    //}

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return TopViewController.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return TopViewController.PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use LINQ in GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations if you wish

Comment: So this is a complete different class? Just wondering as i have homeViewController on app launch and it is a navigation controller. Should i put this code in that class or create another one?

Comment: Updated answer to include navigation controller. All "internal" controllers are derived from base controller as shown in answer. You can define SupportingLandscapeScreenTypes  as static to avoid multiple instances

Comment: I use navigation controller for other purposes you might not need to derive from it or change it

Comment: can you please explain how you derive your controllers from the base?

Comment: public MyController : BaseView

Comment: I like this approach. Minor nit:  `BaseView` would be better named `BaseViewController` or `BaseVC` or `BaseController`; it isn't a `View`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve agree. The only thing I am using this pattern for other platforms and there it is not a controller (sometimes it is activity, sometimes it is a fragment). I wanted to keep it consistent name, that's why it is generic.